# What are all measurable maps $f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ such that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$?

Tags: analysis

Is there a nice description of all nonzero measurable functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)\ $ for all $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

This is inspired by the question [Multiplicative Analytic Functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/52255/multiplicative-analytic-functions/), Theo Buehler's comments there, and idle curiosity.   The only examples I know have the form $f(z)=|z|^cz^k$ or $f(z)=|z|^c\overline z^k$ for some $c\in[0,\infty)$ and nonnegative integer $k$.  A subquestion is: Are these all of them? (Answer: No, see update.)

I tried searching, and found that nonzero multiplicative maps from a semigroup to the multiplicative semigroup of complex numbers are sometimes called semicharacters, and other times called characters, but so far this hasn't helped me find anything that answers this question.

**Update**: I found from reading a remark in Grillet's [*Commutative semigroups*](http://books.google.com/books?id=7QOOxYbCpggC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) that if $f$ is an example, then so is the function $g$ defined by $g(0)=0$, $g(z)=f(z)/|f(z)|$ if $z\neq 0$, and $g$ maps into the unit circle unioned with $\{0\}$.  This then made me realize that if $f$ and $g$ are examples, then so is the function $h$ defined by $h(0)=0$, $h(z)=f(z)/g(z)$ if $z\neq 0$.  So there are examples I did not include above.  I would have to include $f(0)=0$, $f(z)=|z|^cz^k$ where $c$ is any real number and $k$ any integer.

Also, I'm not even sure about what all of the continuous examples are.

Comment: So I am pretty sure that all pathological solutions to the Cauchy functional equation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation) are non-measurable. If that's true then $|f(z)| = |z|^n$ for some $n$ and it shouldn't be hard to conclude from here.

Comment: Yes, it is true that the only measurable solutions of the Cauchy equation are of the form $cx$. For the complex version, can one always split off the action on the norm from the action on the argument?

Comment: ^ The relationship with Cauchy's functional equation can be seen by looking at the function $\ln|f(e^z)|$. Also, it looks more symmetrical to describe the general form as $f(z) = z^a\bar{z}^b$ in my opinion. (I'm just saiyan.)

Comment: @anon Yes $g(z)=\ln{|f(e^z)|}$ gives rise to $g(z+w)=g(z)+g(w)$, but this is a function on $\mathbb{C}$; usually Cauchy's functional equation is spoken about in the context of (real) functions on $\mathbb{R}$. That's how I interpret Andre's inquiry at least.

Comment: @anon: What are $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Haar) measurable endomorphisms of a locally compact Polish group are always continuous.  In this case, unless $f$ is the constant $0$ map, that means $f$ is already continuous on $\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\}$.  Then, by continuity, there is some real $c$ such that for all nonzero real $r$ we have $|f(r)| = |r|^c$.

We first examine how $f$ behaves on positive real numbers.  In general, for real $r$ we have $f(r) = r^c e^{2 \pi i g(r)}$ for some continuous function $g: \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$.  Multiplicativity of $f$ ensures that $g(1) = 0$ and $g(rs) = g(r) + g(s)$; in other words $g$ is a continuous homomorphism from $(\mathbb{R}^+,\times)$ to $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}, +)$.  There are nontrivial examples of such homomorphism: for example $g(r) = \log(r) + \mathbb{Z}$.  This seems to introduce new solutions.  Does anyone know of a reasonable classification of such homomorphisms?

Edit: it turns out that all such homomorphisms have the form $g(r) = a \log(r) + \mathbb{Z}$ for some real $k$, as indicated by Artin's Algebra text (p 332).

So writing $z$ as $|z| \cdot z/|z|$, it suffices to understand what $f$ looks like on the unit circle.

Writing $f(e^{2\pi i x}) = e^{2 \pi i h(x)}$, we see that what's left is understanding continuous endomorphisms of the group $(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z},+)$, which all have the form $f(r) = kr$ for some integer $k$.

Unfolding all of this, we see that all continuous (and thus all measurable) endomorphisms of $(\mathbb{C}\backslash \{0\},+)$ are indeed of the form $f(z) = e^{2 \pi i g(|z|)} |z|^c z^k$ for some real $c$ and integer $k$.  Adding $0$ back in, we see that the grand list of solutions is:

- $f(z) = e^{2 a \pi i \log|z|} |z|^c z^k$, $f(0) = 0$
- $f(z) = f(0) = 0$
- $f(z) = f(0) = 1$,

where $z$ above represents a nonzero complex number, $a$ and $c$ are real parameters, and $k$ is an integer parameter.  In particular, this adds a new function $f(z) = e^{2 \pi i \log|z|}$, $f(0) = 0$ to the initial list presented in the problem.

Answer (score 8):

If you're willing to assume all such measurable $f(z)$ are continuous on ${\mathbb C} - \{0\}$ then it's doable. (I prove this for locally integrable $f(z)$ below). First observe $f(1) = f(1)f(1)$ so $f(1) = 0$ or $1$. If $f(1) = 0$, then $f(z) = f(z)f(1) = 0$ for all $z$ and there's not much to say. So assume $f(z) = 1$ in the following.

Next, Since $f(z^n) = f(z)^n$ for all $z$ and all integers $n$, it suffices to find the form of $f(z)$ in a neighborhood of $z = 1$. Equivalently, it suffices to find the form of $g(r,s) = f(e^re^{is})$ for all $(r,s)$ in a neighborhood of the origin. Since $g(0,0) = 1$ and we are assuming $f(z)$ to be continuous, there is a well-defined $h(r,s) = \log(g(r,s))$ on a neighborhood of the origin. The functional equation translates into $h(r_1 + r_2,s_1 + s_2) = h(r_1,s_1) + h(r_2,s_2)$, where as before the variables are near the origin. So the real and imaginary parts of $h(r,s)$ must also satisfy this functional equation.

Since $Re(h)$ and $Im(h)$ are continuous real-valued functions satisfying the functional equation, by the well-known additive case (whose proof works even for functions only defined in a neighborhood of the origin) we have that $Re(h)(r,s) = ar + bs$ and $Im(h)(r,s) = cr + ds$ for some real $a,b,c,$ and $d$. In terms of $g(r,s)$, this gives 
$$g(r,s) = e^{ar + bs}e^{icr + ids}$$
Not every $g(r,s)$ of this form will work globally; since $g(r,s) = f(e^re^{is})$ one must have that $g(r,s+2\pi) = g(r,s)$. This forces $b = 0$ and $d$ to be a multiple of $2\pi$. So we have $$f(e^re^{is}) = g(r,s) = e^{ar}e^{icr + ins}$$
Here $n$ is an integer. Equivalently where $m$ denotes $a - n$, we have (for $z \neq 0$):
$$f(z) = |z|^me^{ic\ln|z|}z^n$$
Conversely, since each of the factors $|z|^m$, $e^{ic\ln|z|}$ and $z^n$ satisfy the functional equation so do their product. Thus these are exactly the functions continuous on ${\mathbb C} - \{0\}$ satisfying the functional equation, other than the zero function.

Now back to why measurable examples are always continuous. Based on ccc's answer it seems there is a general theory that gives this. For locally integrable $f(z)$ it can be proven directly. Let $\phi(z)$ be a bump function with integral 1 supported on a neighborhood of the origin. Then for any $z$ and $w$ you have
$$f(z)f(w)\phi(w) = f(zw)\phi(w)$$
Integrate both sides with respect to $w$. You get
$$f(z) = \int f(zw)\phi(w)\,dw$$
Doing a change of variables this becomes
$$= {1 \over |z|^2}\int f(w)\phi(z^{-1}w)\,dw$$
(We assume $z \neq 0$). By the dominated convergence theorem the right-hand side is continuous (even smooth) as a function of $z$, so that $f(z)$ is a continuous function.

Comment: For the general theory see [this MO-thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57616). (It is more than a bit shameful that I participated there myself and didn't see it, but I got myself horribly confused last night...)

Comment: Ah, this appeared while I was editing.  It looks like we came to the same conclusion in any case.  I don't know how I missed the last step in my argument for so long, but it's nice to see a different approach.